# Adding filled circular rings (digitized) in vector layer

Tags: qgis, circularstring

I digitize different habitats in one nature reserve. There was 40 ponds - I use "add circular string" option to give them a nice rounded shape. When I finish this 40 ponds I was instructed also to do as a separate part of that layer - area surrounding these 40 ponds as "Early successful grassland".

How can I "clip inside" of this polygon "Early successful grassland" these rounded 40 ponds? I found that option "add circular string" is not supported when I try to use this option together with options "Add Ring" or "Fill Ring". How I can add to the polygon a nice rounded and filled rings?

Currently I use QGIS 2.18, but I check also new version of QGIS 3.0 and there was also missed connection between those features. I try use also Freehand Editing Plugin in QGIS 2.18, but there was also missed connection between features "Add Ring" and "Fill Ring". Is it there some kind of solution for this problem?
I add picture to show how it looks like.

[image]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I find it a little difficult to understand your question, but maybe you need to cut out the area of ​​lakes from pasture area and then, if necessary, merge these two layers into one ...

Comment: Cyril How I can cut out the area of lakes from pasture area? I have done this by - extract of ponds nodes and then I use "Add Ring" option and I connect all of extracted nodes (it was TOO MUCH of work) and I would like to know some easier and faster way to do this

Comment: To do this, you need to run the geo-tool Vector-> Geoprocessing-> Symmetric Difference ...

Answer (score 1):

I try to add another polygon layer.
By using *Rectangles Ovals Digitizing* plugin and *clipper* plugin.

1. Create a circle polygon in the other layer
2. Select 1 and copy it from the other layer
3. Paste 2 to the original layer
4. Move 3 to the polygon which you want to add or fill ring
5. By select 3 and use *clipper*
6. Delete 3 if you want to add ring, or keep it if you want to fill ring